# How to make background color same as image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I'm trying to set an image center of the screen, and the dimension of the image is not as big as the entire screen. How can I make the background color seem like part of the image? Thus creating the illusion that the image is full screen?

I tried using the color of the image and setting it as part of background color, but it still doesn't match.

**html**

```
  <section class="container">
    <img class="bg-img" src="../assets/beauty-bg-img.jpg" alt="background image">
  </section>
```

**css**

```
.container {
    background-color: #F3D5DB;
}
```

As can be seen, the image is centered, but image and background color doesnt go hand in hand.

How can this be done?

[image: background]

Comment: The color of that image is gradient, not solid all the way through. I don't think you can fix that without a gradient background. Look at the top and bottom of the image to see this. The image is lighter than your background on top, and darker on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: That's the issue @Cubemaster The image itself doesn't have a solid color, and your right, it's some gradient. So it isn't possible then after all.

Comment: Another option if you can edit the original image is to change it to fade to transparent at the edges so that it will blend with your background colour better. Or if this isn't an option you may be able to do something similar by overlaying an image that is mostly transparent but fading to your background colour at the edges.

Comment: Hmm interesting, let me edit my original image @Chris I may be able to make the edges fade

Comment: Hey Dood - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to ask for more help. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. ***Also take a moment upvote (instead-of or in-addition-to) the checkmark, to reward answers that were also helpful - it costs nothing but helps us*** If no answer was helpful, please post your own and select it with the checkmark to close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

You could try using 'mix-blend-mode', the background color of your image will match with the background color of it's parent.

Please note that this might not work with your image since you are using a gradient or it could happen that your gradient will be replaced by only one color.

It's also not compatible with some browsers.

```css
.container {
    background-color: #F3D5DB;
}

.bg-img {
    mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_mix-blend-mode.asp) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

The color of your background is solid, but the Image you have selected has a very slight gradient. To see this, Look at the top and bottom of the image to see this. The image is lighter than your background on top, and darker on the bottom of the screen.

[image]

You could fix this using [gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), but that would require a fair bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

There are sooooo many ways at going with this. You could match the gradient perfectly, set the image as the background and make it cover the page. Gradients would be really hard to perfectly match up though, and you didn't ask for the second one. My solution is to use some simple css and a free photo editor. (You dont have to do any photo editing, I have the image). I took the colors from the top and bottom of the original image and then set a css gradient. `background-image: linear-gradient(#F4DAE2, #EED5DC, #EED1D8);` Super easy! Then you just set your body's min-height property to 100vh so nothing repeats. We use paint.net or photoshop to erase the edges of the image in a gradient pattern. Anyone can do this. 
[image: face]
You can get the gradient image file from https://i.ibb.co/0BbJ6bb/face.png. We put that image in the center of the page and everything blends nicely! It's been almost a year so please mark this answer or another as the solution to close the question. Thank you!

Demo page here: https://stackoverflowanswer.glitch.me/

```css
img {
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F4DAE2, #EED5DC, #EED1D8);
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>html - How to make background line up with image</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>  
  <body>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0BbJ6bb/face.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can set the image as background on the body, or on a wrapper div, and use `background-size` property to `cover`.

Or, you can create a stand-alone div at the top of your code, make it `position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100vw;height:100vh;` *(sets the image to full size of the viewport)* and `z-index:-1` *(places it beneath the other divs)*. This is a nice effect because you can also add `opacity:0.5` or some such to "dim" the image a little bit, and the rest of your webpage overlays the image.

Here are some good articles on what you can do:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/backgrounds-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/responsive-background-image/

https://www.taniarascia.com/background-position-fixed-and-cover-with-css/